# State of Application in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to know what will happen to the application when certain interruption occurs. Its related to iOS. Questions are :

1. What will happen to the application when application is launched and is in active state and user receives the incoming call??
2. What will happen to the application when application does some
   downloading operation and user receives the incoming call (I would
   like to know whether the application will continue downloading in
   background or not)??
3. What will happen to the application when application does some
   transcoding operation and user receives the incoming call (I would
   like to know whether the application will continue transcoding or
   not)??
4. What will happen to the application when application is playing the
   video and when user receives the incoming call??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case when a call is coming, the application is sent to background and you will receive the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and the `applicationDidEnterBackground` callback on the `AppDelegate`. To answer your items:

1. Happens what I described.
2. The downloading will stop if the system is not instructed to do otherwise: [iOS Background downloads when the app is not active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861390/ios-background-downloads-when-the-app-is-not-active)
3. If transcoding is happening in the foreground, then it's the same situation as in 1.
4. The video playback will stop, however, audio can continue if the app requested the `App plays audio` background mode and it set up an audio session: [App plays background audio not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240741/app-plays-background-audio-not-working)

There are special cases when these behaviors may be different but those have to be investigated in context.

Comment: thanks for clarifying my doubt. I have one more doubt. I have list of files in my app , I have selected some files and delete operation is performed. At that time, if I receive any incoming call what will happen?? Does the app moves to background and continues the delete operation???

Comment: This needs to be tested and highly depends on how you implemented the deletion. This is one of the "context dependent" cases I mentioned.

Comment: Otherwise, please don't forget to vote and/or accept if you like an answers. It takes a lot of effort to write these. :)