# My iOS app plays audio in background, but when I press the home button the playback stops

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, background, playback

I have a WebView based app that it's supposed to play YouTube videos' audio in the background while the device is Locked or the app is running in the background. By the way, the app uses the AVFoundation framework to handle all the audio related stuff.

Now, the problem is that the app pauses the audio playback when enters to background mode (When I lock the device or I press home), but the audio continues if I play it again from the control center. What I need is to avoid the app stopping the playback when entering background.

(Please remember that the app already has the ability to play audio in background.)

My code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sleep(9.5);

    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController ()

    @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the url into the webview
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://relaxemy.com"];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Try to attempt solution from this article:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295401/audio-playing-while-app-in-background-ios

Comment: Is that because of `sleep(9.5)` somehow?

Comment: @SanitLee Nop, that is to delay the Launch screen.